# Python Selenium Value select

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Can someone help me please, I have been stuck in one place in my script for 2 days .
A menu should be clicked and an option should be selected, unfortunately it does not work, I have started about 50 code attempts, unfortunately without success

This is the html text for which I need a Selenium code solution

```
<select class="categoryAttributesSelect form-control"><option value="-1">Bitte Zustand auswählen...</option><option value="22">Neu</option><option value="2546">Neuwertig</option><option value="23">Gebraucht</option><option value="24">Defekt</option></select>
```

I need a code that selects the option (new) for me

This not Working..

```py
minimenu1 = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/select'))
minimenu1.select_by_visible_text("Neu")
minimenu1.select_by_value("22")
```

Comment: Can you share the code you tried thats not working?

Comment: minimenu1 = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/select'))
minimenu1.select_by_visible_text("Neu")
minimenu1.select_by_value("22")

Comment: I recommend breaking up the `Select` from the `find_element`.  It will make debugging and editing in the future a little easier.

Comment: I would recommend providing the URL for the site that you're scraping, because it is hard to troubleshoot your error messages without more details.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works.

```
minimenu1 = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[contains(@class,'categoryAttributesSelect')]"))
minimenu1.select_by_visible_text("Neu")
```

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: The error is too long to post, I uploaded it to pastebin, hope that's okay: D https://pastebin.com/7yswVw2Z

Comment: Can you check the element you are trying to access is inside a frame?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **below code  :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
menu = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select.categoryAttributesSelect.form-control"))))
menu.select_by_visible_text('Neu')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! now its Working :)

Comment: @Newby :  Can we close this ticket now ? You have to accept it in order to close this ticket, once close it will be marked in green color for future readers. please feel free click on check mark which is right aside with voting buttons. I'd appreciate your time and response on this.